# Open source comment systems

Tags: php, comments

I have a custom php cms managing multiple sites from one path with a wildcard configuration.  I'd like to add a comment system for each unique domain+uri, and am interested in what's currently available before attempting something custom.  Can you recommend any that you're aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://ratherodd.com/commentator/ might be useful. But Even [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/php-com-sys/) looks pretty good

Comment: same here - I'll give it a shot

Answer (score 1):

Add following code to your functions.php file.

```
function custom_hook_after_logo() {
?> 
<div class="header-search-form">
<?php echo get_search_form( false ); ?>
</div>
<?php 
}
add_action( 'rtp_hook_after_logo', 'custom_hook_after_logo' );
```

and add following style to your style.css file

```
.header-search-form{ float : right; }
```

your requirement will be accomplished by this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another one, Commentics  http://www.commentics.org/